# Determine if Any Row Meets Certain Condition in Dataset

Tags: reporting-services

I'm creating a report in visual studio, and I have a dataset which returns rows from a stored procedure. Each row has a column with a date in it. I also have another date passed in as a parameter to the report. I would like to go through the rows, and check if any of them have a date that is less than the date parameter. Is there a way to create a boolean variable for the report which gets set based on this logic?

This is what I currently have, but I get an error saying "`references outside of a data region must be contained within aggregate functions which specify a dataset scope`"

```
=IIF((Fields!ColumnDate.Value, "Dataset") < Parameters!ParameterDate.Value, "value 1", "value 2)
```

Comment: I think your only issue is referring to the dataset when you don't need to. Just remove the `, "Dataset"` and it should work in a table that's already using that Dataset as the source. When using the `, "Dataset"`, you are referring to the WHOLE dataset and the expression would need an Aggregate function to get one value such as MAX, MIN, FIRST...but since you're going row by row, you should not use the Dataset reference.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a workaround by using Min to only compare the lowest date with the parameter:

```
=IIF(Min(Fields!ColumnDate.Value, "Dataset") < Parameters!EndDate.Value, "value 1", "value 2")
```

Comment: What you are calling a DataSet is probably a DataTable.  DataSets contain DataTable among other things. A DataTable contains the rows and columns. Things become a bit easier when you get the vocabulary straightened out.

Comment: I am not sure of the context of that line of code but IIF has been replaced by If(Boolean expression, true, false) which is useful as it is shortcurcuited)

Comment: The vocab is correct, this is SSRS and DataSets are valid as is the IIF() function. The problem is the question was tagged VB.Net as well as reporting-services. I've removed the tag

Comment: Is this what you want? This is only comparing the HIGHEST value of the whole dataset to the parameter, not comparing each row of data. If you're looking for any that are LOWER than the parameter, then you should use MIN.